# Why is Illustrator not making sublayers for each new path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I just downloaded a Ai file from Creative Banner. I needed to use one of their banner templates to help design a curved banner for our client. I noticed on the Design Area/Bleed Area layer that every time I make a new path or object that it doesn't create a new sublayer. All objects or paths stay on that one layer. I can select the objects separately by clicking on them on the art board, but I cannot select them separately in the layers panel.

I can create a new sublayer by clicking on the icon in the layers panel, but otherwise Illustrator puts each new item on the same layer. If you look at the sublayer I created, Layer 8, both object 1 and object 2 and text are all on the same layer. I find this annoying since I'm used to using the layers panel to see the order of my paths/objects, or to select them without trying to find them on the art board.

[image]

Can someone help me figure out how to get it back to the default of making a new sublayer for each new path?

Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

In the **Layers Panel Menu**, under **Panel Options...**, make certain `Show Layers Only` is not checked.

[image]